# Loading DER file into BouncyCastle private key

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I am trying to read a ECC DER private key file to create a BouncyCastle private key in c#.

```
//Load File
byte[] derKeyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.der");
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(derKeyBytes);
```

I am getting following error.

```
wrong version for private key info
```

Comment: It is in the post 2 lines. Thank you.

Comment: The error suggests the file is valid ASN.1, but is not a valid encoding of a (PKCS#8) PrivateKeyInfo structure. If you could give more information about how the test.der file was created, it should be possible to figure out how to parse it. A common case might be that it is encrypted (i.e. an EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo structure), for which you could use PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey, assuming you have the passphrase.

Comment: I will work on what you mentioned. Thank you Peter.